# Make a Word document smaller programmatically by optimizing its structure

Tags: .net, ms-word

We are using .NET and a 3rd party tool (Spire.doc) to render mail merge documents, but they tend to be rather big, like 50-200 MB (keeping the data source and the template separate would do the job, but producing rendered versions with hundreds of pages to download in a single doc *is* the customer request).

Is there a (.NET accessible) library that **minimizes the size of a Word document not by using a compression algorithm** on the file (zip, rar,..), but **by analysing the document structure and then optimizing it** internally and thus making it smaller? So that the result is a valid Word doc(x) (and not an archive or a RTF document).

Optimizing embedded images doesn't help too much because there aren't any.

Comment: What do you mean with "by optimizing the document structure"? Have you a concrete example?

Comment: No, I just want to make the whole doc smaller without looking into it. Sort of a generic algorithm. I'll edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: This might be useful http://superuser.com/questions/6843/minimize-file-size-of-microsoft-word-documents

Comment: @Mehran: nice link, but more useful for embedded media, which we don't have in the document. And we need to script it.

Comment: @Olaf: Do you have any evidence to believe this is possible?

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: I have now. There's a commercial tool from balesio (http://www.balesio.com/fileminimizer/deu/order.php?req=office), I checked, it works (the GUI does, which we cannot use). They also have an SDK (I asked for a quote). But in addition to that, I felt it should be - after all, there is usually a lot of noise in Word documents.

Comment: What format are the docs in after merge - is it RTF?  If you open one and save as docx, how does the size change?

Comment: No, one can choose between doc and docx, but the size varies only slightly. I tried RTF, but it destroys too much of the formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing lots of research, the only tool we found was a commercial one: http://www.balesio.com/fileminimizersdk/eng/index.php. They don't even have prices on their website, nor demo versions, so I can't say anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you think it's the merge function adding extra space, you could do your merge and then create another doc copying the text from the merged doc and pasting into the other one.  I'm not sure why a mail merge would add a bunch of space, though, unless it's storing all the connection details in the .doc file.

Comment: I believe it's just the amount of almost identical pages. It may still be worth a try, but copying the text from one document to another still requires a 3rd party component and some code (unless we use interop, which we don't want to), and we are already using one. My hope was to find something simple and straightforward.